# How to clear cell/range contents?

Tags: vba, excel

**Here is my code,**

```
Sub Clear_click()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2" & lastrow).ClearContents
End Sub
```

As Excel has many rows, how do I start from clearing contents from the second row lets say eg.(**A2**) to a last row of data. The last row of data could be anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgotten column in specified range

```
Range("A2:A" & lastrow).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the rows probably with a for next loop and delete entire row like this:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```

or delete all rows in required range like this:

```
Rows("2:" & lastrow).delete
```